# What does '[A' do in a print command?

Tags: python, printing

I have seen this `'[A'` in a progress bar module but I can't figure out what it does.

As in:

```
print '[]', chr(27) + '[A'
```

Do you know what it does??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a [VT100 Escape sequence](http://www.termsys.demon.co.uk/vtansi.htm); it moves the cursor  up.

Note that the `chr(27)` initiates the sequence. Often, this might be written`"\033[A"` (since `33oct == 27dec`). If you've ever added color to a bash prompt, you've seen this.

Comment: Note that you need more than just the `"[A"` to do this.

Comment: Well, _likely_ to be a VT100 escape sequence. In reality, it's just a sequence of characters. Maybe the ASR33 used that sequence to move the cursor _left_ :-)

Comment: Thanks Ignacio, there is much more code to the module.  It was just this `'[A` that I didn't understand.  Cheers

Comment: To be clear, it's not the `'[A'` that is the escape sequence, but rather the `chr(27) + '[A'` (which can alternatively be written as `'\x1b[A'`.

Answer (score 0):

VT100 escape sequence.

`ESC[<value>A` moves the cursor up `<value>` lines.  It looks like if `<value>` is omitted it defaults to one line.

Comment: The docs say that without `<value>` the default is 1, so I guess is just goes up one line, not to the beginning of the current line?